# arch linux, x220, sd card reader

Tags: arch-linux, sd-card

I'm running ArchLinux on a Thinkpad X220. The laptop has a built-in SD/MMC card reader. When inserting SD cards, no card is detected, nothing is logged to `dmesg`.

The reader is listed in `lshw` as

> ```
>   *-pci3
>         *-generic  
>             description: SD Host controller
>             product: MMC/SD Host Controller
>             vendor: Ricoh Co Ltd
>             physical id: 0
>             bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
>             version: 07
>             width: 32 bits
>             clock: 33MHz
>             capabilities: msi pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>             configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
>             resources: irq:16 memory:f1400000-f14000ff
> ```

`dmesg | grep mmc` lists

> ```
>             sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: No vmmc regulator found
>             sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: No vqmmc regulator found
>             mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:0d:00.0] using DMA
> ```

and `lsmod | egrep (mmc|sdhci)` shows

> ```
>             mmc_block              34914  0
>             sdhci_pci              22137  0 
>             sdhci                  39051  1 sdhci_pci
>             mmc_core              110515  3 mmc_block,sdhci,sdhci_pci
> ```

I also tried inserting the SD card before booting or using `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`, but without success.

Does anybody have a hint how to get it working?

---

Edit: additional information:

`uname -r`: `3.18.6-1-ARCH`

`lspci`: `0d:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)`

---

Edit2: Does also not work using Debian Live-Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me.

SD-Card reader has to be set `enabled` in BIOS.